# How can I prevent third-party content from overwriting my jQuery plugins?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that is comprised of a navigation bar and content. Both are combined into a single HTML document, in that order. I have no control over the content.

I need to include jQuery and register some plugins in my navigation bar, but this is a problem if the content also includes jQuery. It will overwrite the existing jQuery object and my plugins will be lost.

The only solution I've come up with is moving my jQuery to the end of the document, but this is problematic, as it may prevent the navigation bar from being usable during load.

How can I prevent third-party content from wiping out my jQuery plugins when it loads it's own jQuery?

Comment: Could you make it so the scripts are only loaded/initialized if the object doesn't already exist?

Comment: @Jaxo: I have no control over the content.

Comment: Use noConflict(), see jQuery API docs

Comment: @charlietfl: Unless I'm missing something, `noConflict` doesn't do anything useful if a subsequent script loads jQuery without calling `noConflict`.

Comment: but you already said you can move to end of body, then have your plugins right after it. Use `noConflict(true)` Not clear what the dynamics are of other content loading scripts

Comment: @charlieftl: This is problematic because it makes the navigation bar unusable for a potentially long period during load. The content can be literally anything; it's HTML that is pasted into the response body.

Comment: can still use noConflict at top, pass new alias into nav plugins instead of `jQuery`